# What do I need to install on my VPS server to work with CSS LESS?

Tags: ruby, node.js, less, linuxbrew

It seems like there's a long list of things I need to install just to work with LESS, so I want to make sure I have this right:

- To install LESS I need to install node.js/npm
- To install node, I need to install Ruby
- To install Ruby, I need to install Linuxbrew
- To install Linuxbrew, I need to install Git
- To install Git, I need to use/install Yum

FWI, I've never used the console much before, so this might be completely wrong, but it's what I've pieced together so far.

Comment: What distro is it?

Comment: Red Hat, is that what you mean?